# Function console.logs() the intended result but does not return it?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fetch, es6-promise

1. I have a function that makes a fetch call to a particular site for data.
2. Then, I must filter that data based on the parameter passed in the function.
3. I must return the match or matches from this array of data.
4. Save the output of the function to a CONST, pass in the parameter, and log the result.

My code doing the above and `returning`:

- When I `return`, I get undefined.
- When I `console.log` I get the correctly filter objects.

**Returning (not properly, returns undefined)**

```
const fetchData = ({ name, num }) => {

    const request = fetch(`apiLink`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          // If the name parameter was passed, filter for it
          if (name) {
            return (data.filter(person => person.name.includes(name)));
          }

        })
        .catch(() => {
          console.error('oh no');
      })
}


const res = fetchData({
  name: 'Tina',
});
console.log(res); // undefined via return
```

**Console logging the result actually shows the filter data**

```
const fetchData = ({ name, num }) => {

    const request = fetch(`apiLink`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          // If the name parameter was passed, filter for it
          if (name) {
            console.log((data.filter(person => person.name.includes(name)));
          }

        })
        .catch(() => {
          console.error('oh no');
      })
}


const res = fetchData({
  name: 'Tina',
});
console.log(res);
```

Can anyone help me understand why it is returning undefined? And how I can return and filter properly (after the data is fetched)?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Use async/await or resolve the promise.

Comment: I have to only use ES6 :/

Comment: @wolfie777 Then return the Promise, and `then()` it where you need the value.

Comment: I thought that's what I was doing! any pointers to help me out? I thought I was returning the filtered data after the promise since it is 2 .thens deep.

Comment: You're not returning anything from your `fetchData()` function. The `return` applies to the surrounding function which is the callback arrow function `data => { ... }`. You're only returning from your `then` callback. You'll need to return the `request` variable from your `fetchData()` function and then use `.then()` on the returned promise. Like `fetchData({ name: 'Tina' }).then(data =>  console.log(data));`

Comment: I am doing just as you suggested by chaining the .then `fetchData({ name: 'Tina' }).then(data =>  console.log(data));` but when I return the data (not console.log it), it still says undefined.  `fetchData({ name: 'Tina' }).then(data =>  data);`